# Python- Variable Scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Interface():
     Number = input("Enter number: ")

Interface()
print(Number)
```

This is a small simplified snippet of my code which produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jack/Documents/Python/NumberToText.py", line 78, in 
    print(Number)
NameError: name 'Number' is not defined
```

I underdstand this is because the variable is defined in a function.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Well, actually I've seen some question like this about three times. And most of them got lot's of downvotes. But this one got three upvotes and none of downvotes now. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: Perharps becuase of the way I asked it. @KevinGuan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

Probably making the `Interface` function return `Number` would be the easiest solution

```
def interface():
     number = input("Enter number: ")
     return number

print(interface())
```

Please see [this SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) on the topic of scope rules in python

Note: as you can see, I have converted the names of the function and the variable to lowercase, following the [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guideline

Comment: You would drop the unneeded brackets of course: `return number`. `return` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Because variable `Number` only belongs function `Interface()`. You can use `return` like this:

```
def Interface():
     number = int(input("Enter number: "))
     # remember use int() function if you wish user enter a number

     return(number)

print(Interface())
```

or use `global` just like this:

```
def Interface():
     global number
     number = input("Enter number: ")
     # remember use int() function if you wish user enter a number

Interface()
print(number)
```

And only use `global` when you need the variable can use at everywhere or you need the function return other things. Because modifying globals will breaks modularity.

[Here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names) is the document about what is global variable.